# Retrieving XML attributes of unknown quantity

Tags: c#, xml

I have requirement to read an XML file. I've never done anything with XML so it's all new territory for me. Please refer to the below XML sample.

```
-
<GPO xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">+
  <Identifier>
    <Name>GB Local Server Access</Name>
    <IncludeComments>true</IncludeComments>
    <CreatedTime>2011-08-03T11:58:18</CreatedTime>
    <ModifiedTime>2011-08-03T12:13:41</ModifiedTime>
    <ReadTime>2014-10-21T11:32:49.5863908Z</ReadTime>+
    <SecurityDescriptor>----------------------------
      <FilterDataAvailable>true</FilterDataAvailable>-
      <Computer>
        <VersionDirectory>18</VersionDirectory>
        <VersionSysvol>18</VersionSysvol>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>-
        <ExtensionData>-
          <Extension xsi:type="q1:SecuritySettings" xmlns:q1="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security">-
            <q1:RestrictedGroups>-
              <q1:GroupName>
                <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-21-1547161642-1214440339-682003330-1141792</SID>
                <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">CRB\DKCPHGITSCOM</Name>
              </q1:GroupName>-
              <q1:Memberof>
                <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-32-544</SID>
                <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">BUILTIN\Administrators</Name>
              </q1:Memberof>
            </q1:RestrictedGroups>-
            <q1:RestrictedGroups>-
              <q1:GroupName>
                <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-21-1547161642-1214440339-682003330-1151</SID>
                <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">CRB\GB Administrators</Name>
              </q1:GroupName>-
              <q1:Memberof>
                <SID xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">S-1-5-32-544</SID>
                <Name xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types">BUILTIN\Administrators</Name>
              </q1:Memberof>
            </q1:RestrictedGroups>
```

Please could you advise on the simplest method that I can use that will allow me to drill down to **GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension.RestrictedGroups** and then **FOR EACH** instance of **RestrictedGroups** return the value of **GroupName.Name and MemberOf.Name**. I can then incorporate the logic to get this data into an array of some sort ready to be output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use LINQ to XML.

Something like:

```
//preparing the reusable XName instances:
var q1Namespace = "http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Settings/Security";

var groupNameElementName = XName.Get("GroupName", q1Namespace);
var memberOfElementName = XName.Get("Memberof", q1Namespace);

var nameElementName = XName.Get("Name", "http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/Types");

var data = XDocument.Load(filePath)
    .Descendants(XName.Get("RestrictedGroups", q1Namespace))
    .Select(group =>
        new
        {
            GroupName =
                group.Descendants(groupNameElementName)
                    .Select(gn => gn.Element(nameElementName).Value)
                    .FirstOrDefault(),

            MemberOfName =
                group.Descendants(memberOfElementName)
                    .Select(gn => gn.Element(nameElementName).Value)
                    .FirstOrDefault()
        });
```

Then use it in foreach loop:

```
foreach (var d in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group name: {0}, member of name: {1}", d.GroupName, d.MemberOfName);
}
```

If you'd like to make it safe and provide default values for the names, use something like the below instead of the `Select` call which finds the *Name* element:

```
...
    .SelectMany(gn => gn.Elements(nameElementName))
    .Select(elem => elem.Value ?? "Name not found")
    .DefaultIfEmpty("Name not found")
    .FirstOrDefault()
```

This way you will protect yourself from the cases where the *Name* element does not exist or has no value.

Comment: Could you give an example, how I might then use this, lets say I want to iterrate through the list as part of a for each loop.

Comment: Done, you can see the usage now.

Comment: Thanks, however the above is not generating any data. The var data is empty (foreach loops exits immediately). The XML contains quite a deep structure, could I ask you to check the elements/descendents once more please?

Comment: Could you put an example of a full XML somewhere I can download it?

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/gpreport - Sorry, was the quickest method I could find. You'll have to enter a captcha code to get it. Thank you again.

Comment: OK, there was both my wrong API usage and absent information about *q1* namespace. See the fixed solution.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for this. You've saved a lot of work. One more question if I may.. Any tips or suggestions on how I might go towards trapping errors that occur when attempting to .WriteLine GroupName or MemberOf if they are missing from the source XML?

Comment: I fixed the answer so you should have no exceptions.